# Hibernate Connection using C3P0 and Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, c3p0

I am trying to get an application(jadasite) up and running using postgresql and glassfish. The app designers recommend tomcat and mysql. I can not really use tomcat and mysql for this app atm.  The application uses JPA so postgresql should be no problem. The designers do mention that postgresql/many other db's should work.

So here is what I have done Using the following two pages as a reference:

[Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

[Jadasite forums](http://www.jadasite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=75)

```
jada.properties

log4j.directory=/tmp
hibernate.connection.password=password
working.directory=/tmp
encryption.key=fVOew3eAhr+hdZ9eQLeEtw\=\=
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:postgresql:dev-rdbms.example.com:5432/jada"/>
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.drivers

persistence.xml(parital)

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="jada"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://dev-rdbms.example.com:5432/jada>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/
```

I then used mysql2psql to make a postgresql compatible db dump, loaded all data and created appropriate users with appropriate permissions and acces.(tested via psql from server glassfish runs on as well)

So after making the changes I put the lastest postgresql jdbc 4 driver into the applications WEB-INF/lib directory. Made a new war file and deployed it to my glassfish v3.01 server.

I get the following errors. Which appear to me to say C3P0 can not find the JDBC drivers(located in apps WEB-INF/lib directory and also in the glassfish domains lib directory)

[#|2011-04-28T11:34:58.508-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|

```
javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=FelixStartLevel;|WebModule[/jada]JadaSite: Unable to initialize JPA connection
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jadaSite] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
        at com.jada.jpa.connection.JpaConnection.init(JpaConnection.java:79)
        at com.jada.system.Initializer.init(Initializer.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1428)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5007)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:362)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:185)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.inject(AbstractWombImpl.java:174)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb$1.run(ConstructorWomb.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb.initialize(ConstructorWomb.java:84)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.get(AbstractWombImpl.java:77)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:58)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.get(LazyInhabitant.java:107)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:60)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:128)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:457)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:401)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.start(HK2Main.java:125)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:915)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.Main.start(Main.java:140)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1077)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: 
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:118)
        ... 53 more
|#]
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with my connection paramaters or have any idea how C3P0 could be missing these drivers?

**Edit**

I did see some issues that looked like they were caused by C3P0 not finding the drivers so I did try throwing the C3P0 jar into the glassfish lib as well but still got the same errors.  Here is the error from the comment below in a little nicer fasion and more info.

```
[#|2011-04-28T12:37:49.964-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:49,964  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - Mapping collection: com.jada.jpa.entity.ShippingType.shippingMethodRegionTypes -> shipping_method_region_type
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.009-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,008  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.405-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,404  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:286) - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.491-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,490  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.504-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,504  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - C3P0 using driver:  at URL: 
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.506-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,505  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - Connection properties: {user=, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.507-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,506  INFO [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:265) - autocommit mode: true
|#]

[#|2011-04-28T12:37:50.543-0500|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 12:37:50,531 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:535) - JDBC Driver class not found: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
        at com.jada.jpa.connection.JpaConnection.init(JpaConnection.java:79)
        at com.jada.system.Initializer.init(Initializer.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1428)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5007)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:362)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:185)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.inject(AbstractWombImpl.java:174)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb$1.run(ConstructorWomb.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb.initialize(ConstructorWomb.java:84)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.get(AbstractWombImpl.java:77)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:58)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.get(LazyInhabitant.java:107)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:60)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:128)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:457)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:401)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.start(HK2Main.java:125)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:915)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.Main.start(Main.java:140)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1077)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|#]
```

Comment: It looks to me like C3P0 is not picking up on my connection properties. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/connection/C3P0ConnectionProvider.java.html - Lines 103 + 104 a printed in my stack traces and show I am missing the connection paramaters. I have no idea where else those are set other than persistence.xml

Comment: For the bounty this is Jadasite 2.04.02 running on glassfish 3.01 using postgresql as a database. I can get it to run no problems using glassfish 3.01 and mysql(developers use tomcat and mysql). I have also tried tomcat and postgresql with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Two things seem odd here:

1) the stacktrace for ClassNotFoundException does not mention the name of the class that was not found:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

This would seem to imply that it is trying to load a class with no name, otherwise you would expect to see the name of the class that could not be found.

2) Not sure if it's just a copy and paste mistake, but in the snippet of your configuration above, you are missing the end-quote on this line:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" 
     value="jdbc:postgresql://dev-rdbms.example.com:5432/jada>
```

which would make for malformed XML.

3) When you say

> Made a new jar file and deployed it to my glassfish v3.01 server.

Do you mean to say you made a new "war" file, not "jar"? You need to make sure that the postgres jdbc jar is on glassfish's classpath ultimately.

Comment: That are three odd things, not two :)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for catching that Matt, Fixed the copy paste error and I did mean to say a new war. I looked through a few more logs and found this right abovce a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:----  _ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2011-04-28 11:34:58,493 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] (JCLLoggerAdapter.java:535) - JDBC Driver class not found: So I believe the JDBC driver is on the classpath myself seeing as it is in the Glassfish lib directory(has been used by that particular glassfish install in the past) and in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Let try this:

You use EJBs right (JPA means EJB)? So, you have at least one EAR, one JAR and possible one WAR, right? You know, JARs cannot access WARs files. If your postgresql jdbc 4 driver is on WAR/WEB-INF/lib your JARs (which need it) cannot access.

Try put your lib in a EAR lib (look for glassfish doc for that, but is something like EAR/WEB-INF/lib too) or put it on server libraries (something like GLASSFISH_DIR/lib/classes)

Comment: "JPA means EJB" not really, no.

Comment: humm.. Explain pls. How an JPA entity is not an EJB?

Comment: You did not specify JPA entity, JPA by itself would refer to Java Persistence API. I am not sure myself though if all JPA enitys also meet the specs for an EJB 100%.

Comment: And as far as the app is concerned it is packaged as a single war file. I looked through it a bit and did not find any EAR or JAR entitys. But I did not go through it completely. I will take another look and see what I find.

Comment: No other Jada  JAR or EAR files are in the WAR.

Comment: Since you are using C3PO, try to configure it. Put this on hibernate.cfg just for test: hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.drivers` in the properties file? Shouldn't it be `org.postgresql.Driver` instead?

Edit:

Ah! Looks like Jadasite uses the properties file to load the driver class.

From `com/jada/jpa/connection/JpaConnection.java` class:

```
67      
68      public void init(String driver, String url, String user, String password) throws Exception {
69          this.driver = driver;
70          this.url = url;
71          this.user = user;
72          this.password = password;
73          
74          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
75          map.put(Environment.DRIVER, driver);
76          map.put(Environment.URL, url);
77          map.put(Environment.USER, user);
78          map.put(Environment.PASS, password);
79          factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jadaSite", map);
80      }
```

Which is read as (in `com/jada/system/Initializer.java`):

```
 111            if (requireInstall) {
 112                if (!installCompleted) {
 113                    log("Installation has not been done.  Skipping custom initialization.");
 114                    log("Please proceed to installation and remmember to restart before continue.");
 115                    log("Awaiting installation....");
 116                    return;
 117                }
 118                try {
 119                    Properties installProperties = installer.getConfigProperties();
```

Which comes from (in `com/jada/install/process/Installer.java`):

```
 345        public Properties getConfigProperties() throws IOException {
 346            String filename = servletLocation + Constants.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILENAME;
 347            File file = new File(filename);
 348            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
 349            Properties properties = new Properties();
 350            properties.load(input);
 351            return properties;
 352        }
```

Which is read from the file (in `com/jada/util/Constants.java`):

```
 275        public static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "WEB-INF/jada.properties";
```

Comment: I think I am possibly a horrible stack overflower on this one. I had forgotten my original post is so out of date! I did get that initial hibernate.connection.driver_class changed. I also had updated the properties file used by jada, as well as the web.xml.  I still get the same issue, and it is that hibernate never quite passes the proper config info from any location to C3P0. Seeing as you did all the work there and I could have gone back and updated all I am going to give you the bounty